# Filter JavaScript array adding/removing condition one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to filter array of objects with multiple search criteria one by one.

suppose first filter criteria is "x" and then apply "x+y" etc.wherever x or "x+y" matches with array of object,matched result to be displayed.

if user wants to remove "x" or "y",array should respond accordingly.

e.g :here *x=mumbai* and then *y=25*

```
   var users = [{
   name: 'nitin',
   email: 'nitin@mail.com',
   age: 25,
   address: 'mumbai'
   },
   {
    name: 'pawan',
    email: 'pan@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'kolkata'
   },
   {
    name: 'sudip',
    email: 'sudip@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'mumbai'
   }];

  this.searchGridText = "";
  this.users = this.users.filter((data) => {
  const stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
  const filtered = stringified.replace(/"\w+":/gm, '');

  return (filtered.toLowerCase()
    .indexOf(this.searchGridText.toLowerCase().trim()) !== -1);

  });
```

when search criteria is "Mumbai",two record should return and then search criteria is 25,one record should return.if Mumbai search criteria removed,then only record matching to 25 should display.search criteria will be enter in text box and when enter key is hit,then filter will apply on array of objects.

Comment: why you use this event.target.value.toLowerCase().trim()?

Comment: small mistake ..replace  "event.target.value" by "this.searchGridText"

Comment: How exactly get the condition passed?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this via [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```js
var users = [{ name: 'nitin', email: 'nitin@mail.com', age: 25, address: 'mumbai' }, { name: 'pawan', email: 'pan@mail.com', age: 35, address: 'kolkata' }, { name: 'sudip', email: 'sudip@mail.com', age: 28, address: 'mumbai' } ]; 

let findUsers = (arr, filters) => {
  let fs = filters.split('+').map(x => x.trim().toLowerCase())
  return arr.filter(x => {
    let vs = Object.values(x)
    return fs.every(f => vs.some(v => v.toString().trim().toLowerCase().includes(f)))
  })
}

console.log(findUsers(users, 'mumbai'))
console.log(findUsers(users, 'mumbai + 25'))
console.log(findUsers(users, 'sudip'))
```

The idea is to filter and inside get the values of each object and iterate over them trying to match the passed to the function filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your same idea but turning it into a function, and that is discriminating little by little by the characteristics that you are looking for

```js
var users = [{
    name: 'nitin',
    email: 'nitin@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'mumbai'
  },
  {
    name: 'pawan',
    email: 'pan@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'kolkata'
  },
  {
    name: 'sudip',
    email: 'sudip@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'mumbai'
  }
];

this.searchGridText = "mumbai 25";

let filters = searchGridText.split(" ");
let res = [];
for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
  res = filtereds(filters[i]);

  users = res;
}


function filtereds(c) {

  this.users = this.users.filter((data) => {
    const stringified = JSON.stringify(data);
    const filtered = stringified.replace(/"\w+":/gm, '');
    //console.log(c);
    return (filtered.toLowerCase()
      .indexOf(c.toLowerCase().trim()) !== -1);

  });
  return this.users;
}



console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that takes filter keys as an array and filter on those values. You can split the entered value into array using `.split()` and pass it to the function.

```
function searchJson(array, keys) {

  return array.filter(item => {
    const string = item && typeof item === 'object' && JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase();

    return keys.filter(key => string && string.includes(key.toString().toLowerCase())).length === keys.length;
  })
}
```

```js
var users = [{
   name: 'nitin',
   email: 'nitin@mail.com',
   age: 25,
   address: 'mumbai'
   },
   {
    name: 'pawan',
    email: 'pan@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'kolkata'
   },
   {
    name: 'sudip',
    email: 'sudip@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'mumbai'
   }];
   
   function searchJson(array, keys) {

  return array.filter(item => {
    const string = item && typeof item === 'object' && JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase();

    return keys.filter(key => string && string.includes(key.toString().toLowerCase())).length === keys.length;
  })
}

console.log(searchJson(users, ['mumbai', 25]))
```

Comment: You answer doesn't work correctly. If i pass ['mumbai', '25'] it still finds 2 items.

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov are you going to remove your down vote or not?

Comment: your answer is not correct. It is very slow because of stringify and searches not only by user data, bug also by data keys and json symbols ("age", "{" etc)

Comment: @AlexanderDanilov *It is very slow because of stringify and searches*? can you please share your test results, and also I've never heard of an answer being wrong because it's slow. so I've created a little test to compare with the answer below to see which one performs better https://jsbin.com/xivitutara/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

No stringify, no regex and no problems:

```js
function search(array, query) {
    let filters = query.split("+").map(x => x.trim().toLowerCase())
    return users.filter(user => {
        for (let filter of filters) {
            let match = false
            for (let key in user) {
                let value = user[key]
                if (value && value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
                    match = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if (!match) { return false }
        }
        return true
    })
}

let users = [{
    name: undefined,
    email: 'nitin@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'mumbai'
}, {
    name: 'pawan',
    email: 'pan@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'kolkata'
}, {
    name: 'sudip',
    email: 'sudip@mail.com',
    age: null,
    address: 'mumbai'
}]

let result = search(users, "Mumbai + 25");

console.log(result)
```